# Would it be feasible to decelerate a crewed vehicle from ~25 km/s only using the atmosphere of Mars (in the context of an "express transit")?

Tags: mars, crewed-spaceflight, reentry, aerobraking

I boldly assumed it would some day be possible to accelerate a crewed vehicle from a refueling station (LEO, GEO, Moon orbit?) to ~35-40 km/s (with several stages) relative to Mars, so it would make the 70-100(?) million km journey at an average velocity of ~ 30 km/s and encounter Mars with ~25 km/s(?). That would make the transit sort of acceptably short, roughly 1 month long.

Since the escape velocity from Mars is ~5 km/s, the craft would need to be decelerated by at least 20 km/s and since Mars conveniently has an atmosphere I wanted to ask if it would be possible to get the job done purely by atmospheric braking. I realize that this $\Delta V$ of 20 km/s would need to occur in one pass (the remaining 5 km/s would be reduced in a second atmospheric pass to either enter an orbit or land on Mars).

This is about twice the $\Delta V$ of the returns from the Moon, so it would be quite brutal, I assume. If this is definitely impossible the classical way, would it be helpful to use a sacrificial parachute or other device that gets deployed initially, in extremely thin atmosphere, before the main atmospheric braking occurs?

Comment: Thanks @BrendanLuke15 for editing including tags - I seem to have trouble finding appropriate tags: I was looking for "crewed" but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, sorry.

Completely disregarding the (enormous) heat factor of the aerobraking.

The requirement specifies *manned*.
The path through Mars' atmosphere will be very nearly a straight line.
A bit of trig tell us that the path through the atmosphere (up to 5% of surface pressure) is only some 570km long.

Decelerating from 25km/s to 5km/s in 570km, requires an average deceleration of -526.32m/s2
That's an average of 53.65g   (for 38 seconds only)

Your astronauts will be strawberry jam.

P.s.
If you can drop that initial speed to 15km/s, the deceleration drops to 17.9g (58 seconds)
Still very painful, but potentially survivable with some elaborate support structures (we're talking liquid immersion g-bath, and the like)

Comment: This is a nice analysis, how did you arrive at 570km? I can't seem to replicate it

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 took the simple assumption of atmosphere must be 5% or greater of surface. Threw that through a chord vs sagitta of a circle segment calculator. I also tried calculating the drag coefficient needed to achieve such decelerations in Mars atmosphere, and the numbers went *nuts*. craft with ballute 400x its surface area! Plasma temperatures of 60000k! nutz figures, i tell you!

Comment: Apollo was half as fast, and had a much longer way to break - being only a bit above escape velocity gives a nice curve to the flight path - but that won't happen at 5x escape velocity.

Comment: @asdfex Apollo has 1/5th the energy to scrub, and something like 6x the time to do it in. So, at a first ballpark estimate, 30x as "hard" as an Apollo reentry.

Comment: Note that it'd "only" take ~18 gravities to follow the curve of Mars at 25 km/s. You wouldn't be able to brake purely with the atmosphere, but a combination of atmospheric braking, negative aerodynamic lift, propulsive augmentation of said lift, and propulsive braking could result in a rough but survivable braking maneuver that's far more efficient than scrubbing 25 km/s propulsively. Certainly far more difficult and riskier to your health than just packing an additional month or two of consumables, though...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for - also to the commentators. I was aware of the quadratically increasing kinetic energy that would need to be dumped, so I had a hunch that things wouldn't go too well, but I didn't think about the much higher curvature and the lower escape/orbital velocity. Both lead to a much shorter "usable" deceleration length. I assume if Mars was made of tungsten and for some unrealistic reason had the same atmosphere, things would be different?

Comment: It's surprising how many *"Why don't we just..."* questions are adequately answered with some high school physics, a pencil, and half of an envelope.

Comment: @J...: I thought this is a place to get answers to such questions. From my comment above you can see I learned something from the answer and comments and that in addition to the pure calculation: I didn't think about the curvature and orbital velocity being important for the issue. Also, there's no similar question so far and hopefully other people will learn something as well. Good?

Comment: @FelixTritschler It was meant as an observation of how superficially complex questions can actually be quite simple with a bit of reduction.  It wasn't a criticism of the question or the answer.